# I want to move a value from one text field to another text field in one html page using codeigniter

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, codeigniter

I want to move a value from one text field to another text field in one html page using codeigniter. here we can write something or fetch something from db into the first text area. i dont understand how to do that ??

---

Comment: what did you already tried? your wish is not clean, for me sound like. *I want to  boil water using dispenser*.

Comment: You'll need to provide examples of code and be clear about what you're trying to do. From an outsiders point of view, we have no idea what you're really asking.

Answer (score 1):

While your question is far from clear, this will probably help to get you started.

You can use [CodeIgniter sessions](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html), [PHP sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) or just post the value using a form if you need it sent from one page to another.

However, if you need to copy values within a single page, something like [this](http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-form-value.phtml) will do (and has nothing to do with CodeIgniter).